# File Picker without caching Files in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, caching, filepicker, imagepicker

I want to pick files from storage using flutter, but in all libraries the picked file writes to cache immediately and returns the cached URL (/data/data/package/cache...). Sometimes it's OK, but in case of multiple files and large sized files this is not acceptable. I have tried with image_picker,file_picker etc. Is there anything I am missing or any other libraries that can satisfy my requirement? This is happening while testing in android. I didn't test with iOS.

Comment: I do not believe that a file picker would copy the selected files.

Comment: lib versions:  image_picker: ^0.6.7+8
  file_picker: ^2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Use clearTemporaryFiles() method or pick files library below 2.0.0. From version 2.0.0 every file is cached on Android platform.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this method to overcome this

```
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
final directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();
directory.delete(recursive: true);
final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();
......
```

and your rest of the code